# creating a prefix NSString using two NSStrings

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have instructions to make a prefix method that takes two strings for each position where mask = 0 and the first string = second string up until these conditions are not meet that is your prefix NSString.

I made my attempt but for some reason my prefix string is returning as null and I was hoping i could get some help.

here is my method

```
- (void)prefixCalculation:(NSString *)seriesStart SeriesEnd:(NSString *)seriesEnd {

    // call this method when loading the view to get everything set up
    NSLog(@"start %@", seriesStart);
    NSLog(@"end %@", seriesEnd);

    // allocate values so you can use this to create the UITextField
    seriesStartString = seriesStart;
    seriesEndString = seriesEnd;

    // set prefix string

    for (int i = 0; i <= seriesStartString.length ; i++) {

        unichar c1 = [seriesStartString characterAtIndex:i];
        unichar c2 = [seriesEndString characterAtIndex:i];
        if (c1 != c2) {
            break;
        }
        else if (c1 == c2) {

            NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", c1];
            [prefixString appendFormat:@"%@",str];

        }

    }
    NSLog(@"prefix %@", prefixString);

}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but prefixString which is a NSMutableStrong comes back as null, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your code you don't show the initialization of `prefixString`, I take a guess and suggest you to check whether you initialized it or not.

If that's not the case, `prefixString` is `nil` and sending messages to it will fail silently.

Comment: oh man. thought I had done it further up I think i deleted the code earlier when I was trying to use commonPrefixWithString:options: just looked and it wasnt there.. sorry about that I should have looked harder. will accept your answer once the time limit is up